# if and else statement in django

Tags: python, django

I have a search function where a user searches for states. After submit a user  should be redirected to a new page where I want to show some specific info related to found state.

I'm trying to use `if-else` statement but it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I tried:

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">{{ state | title }}</h2>

{% if State == California %}
    <h1>Show this</h1>
{% else %}
    <h1>Show this to all others.</h1>
{% endif %}


{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import models

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')

def chose_state(request):
    state = request.POST.get('state')
    models.State.objects.create(state=state)

    stuff_for_frontend = {
    'state': state,
    }
    return render(request, 'myapp/chose_state.html', stuff_for_frontend)
```

Comment: Isn't `if State == California` supposed to be `if state == 'California'`? Python is case-sensitive, so `State` and `state` mean different things. Also, I'm guessing `California` was supposed to be a string, in which case it must be between quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the error is in the `if State == California` statement, which was supposed to be `if state == 'California'`.

Python is a case-sensitive programming language, so `State` and `state` mean different things. Since you are using the name `state` in your `stuff_for_frontend` dictionary, then use the lowercase version in your view.

Also, `California` was supposed to be a string. In Python, it means it should be enclosed in quotes (either single-quotes `'California'` or double-quotes `"California"`).

Therefore, replace

```py
{% if State == California %}
```

by

```py
{% if state == 'California' %}
```